# Make two database connections available in a model to use in laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, laravel-5, database

I am using 2 connections in my project. One is mysql and another is mongo. I am creating separate database for each user/company.

So while register i need to create 2 database for each type mysql and mongo.

I have added the line just below the regular Eloquent in regular auth user model

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Model as Eloquent;
```

User class is like

`class User extends Eloquent implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract`

I want both the connection to be available in the same model. I can switch the connection to use like

```
DB::connection("connection name")
```

But i need to comment the line

```
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Model as Eloquent;
```

to use mysql and comment the regular Eloquent to use mongo

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;
```

Is there a way out to include both and then can switch the connection anytime without commenting anyone of them.

Looking forward to your support.

Sorry if i sound irrelevant i am new to Laravel

Comment: You can not use more than one class to extends your class. I think you need to use something like Factory pattern in order to create object depending on connection (mysql or mongo).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have tried and its working fine with a single include that is

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;
```

Jenssegers already included and extended the default Eloquent to create functions same alike.

I have configured the package correctly and then using 2 different syntax i can use both database at time.

For Mysql

```
DB::connection("Mysql connection name")->table('table_name')
```

For Mongo

```
DB::connection("Mongo connection name")->collection('table name')
```